# Failed to update XERO certificate

Tags: xero-api

The public key certificate for our XERO App has expired.
We've generated a new public key but when we tried to upload the cert file or paste the cert key we always get a "Failed to update key" message.
Has anyone encountered this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you try upload X509 certificate (.cer file) ?